# Spring 4 Jar overriding Servlet 3 Api

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0, spring-4

I am trying to configure my latest Spring application programmatically instead of with an xml file. However, I am running into a problem where when I import the spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE jar the compiler no longer uses the Servlet 3 api.

I need to have access to methods like: 
ServletContext.addListener(java.lang.Class listenerClass)

and

ServletContext.addServlet(java.lang.String servletName, java.lang.Class servletClass)

But I also need to be able to use spring mvc classes like DispatcherServlet .

Is this a known bug with Spring 4 and does anyone know of any resolution for it?

Comment: I doubt that that comes from adding the spring-webmvc.jar to your classpath. Spring MVC itself also depends on servlet 3.0 for certain classes (like the `SpringServletContainerInitializer` )

Comment: Thats what I have been reading... I have actually managed to fix it by  adding the spring-mvc jar directly to the classpath while adding the servlet 3 jar to the lib folder, although it doesnt seem like it should have to be done that way...

Comment: Aren't you using something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies?!

Comment: No I have never used them before